How can I use the dataset that is stored in google drive while running ML project?
I'm running the SoccerNet project which takes generates subtitles for soccer video.
I'm trying to pass the path to the google drive where dataset is stored that is https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/{folder_id}
the command that I'm running is as follows:
python main.py --SoccerNet_path="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/{folder_id}" --model_name=new_model --features=baidu_soccer_embeddings.npy --framerate=1 --pool=NetVLAD --window_size_caption=45 --window_size_spotting=15 --NMS_window=30 --num_layers=4 --first_stage=caption --pretrain --GPU=0

I'm getting OS Error: as follows
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/{folder_id}?usp=drive_link\\england_epl\\2014-2015\\2015-02-21 - 18-00 Chelsea 1 - 1 Burnley\\1_baidu_soccer_embeddings.npy'

I tried using google colab but I'm not getting the output expected in colab as it is not generating a json file which should contain subtitles as expected.
I'm using VS code.

Hi, you can't access google drive dataset via the link.
You will need to download the dataset and save it locally. Or upload the script to the colab and run it from there. I'm not sure why you didn't get the output 'json' with subtitles when running on the colab, but the resulting file will be generated on the colab if you are runnig from Colab Notebook.

You cannot simply access your Google Drive via a URL: if you can, then I can, too. You need to authenticate the Python (or IPython kernel) process that you grant access to your data. Instructions for 3 use cases are here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=c2W5A2px3doP
